# Understanding output of softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits

Tags: tensorflow

Am new to tensorflow, can someone explain me how did we get answer as 1.16012561.

```
 unscaled_logits = tf.constant([[1., -3., 10.]])
   target_dist = tf.constant([[0.1, 0.02, 0.88]])
   softmax_xentropy = 
   tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=unscaled_logits, 
   labels=target_dist)
   with tf.Session() as sess:
       print(sess.run(softmax_xentropy))
```

Output: [ 1.16012561]

Answer (score 3):

[Here is a good explanation about it](http://peterroelants.github.io/posts/neural_network_implementation_intermezzo02/). It works like this. First, the logits are passed through the [softmax function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function), giving you a probability distribution:

```
import numpy as np

logits = np.array([1., -3., 10.])
# Softmax function
softmax = np.exp(logits) / np.sum(np.exp(logits))
print(softmax)
>>> array([  1.23394297e-04,   2.26004539e-06,   9.99874346e-01])
# It is a probability distribution because the values are in [0, 1]
# and add up to 1
np.sum(softmax)
>>> 0.99999999999999989  # Almost, that is
```

Then, you compute the cross-entropy between the computed softmax value and the target.

```
target = np.array([0.1, 0.02, 0.88])
# Cross-entropy function
crossentropy = -np.sum(target * np.log(softmax))
print(crossentropy)
>>> 1.1601256622376641
```

[`tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) will return you one of these values "per vector" (by default, "vectors" are in the last dimension), so, for example, if your input logits and targets have size 10x3 you will end up with 10 cross-entropy values. Usually one sums or averages these all and uses the result as loss value to minimize (which is what [`tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/softmax_cross_entropy) offers). The logic behind the cross-entropy expression is that `target * np.log(softmax)` will take negative values closer to zero where `target` is more similar to `softmax` and diverge from zero (towards minus infinity) when they are different.

Note: This is a *logical* explanation of the function. Internally, TensorFlow most likely perform different but equivalent operations for better performance and numerical stability.

Comment: TensorFlow neither adds them nor takes the mean over a batch, it just returns a tensor of length `batchsize`, with each element representing the softmax cross entropy between this predicted element and the target element. But you can easily sum them up or take the mean by using `tf.reduce_sum(softmax...)` or `tf.reduce_mean(softmax...)`.

Comment: @ml4294 That's right, updated, thanks. I was thinking of [`tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/softmax_cross_entropy).